# Raspberry Pi PPTP Port Opening

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, pptp

I configured PPTP on my Raspberry Pi with Wheezy image following the guide given in webpage:

http://www.raspberrypihelp.net/tutorials/21-pptp-vpn-server-raspberry-pi

On completion of the configuration all worked well.

I then installed MYSQL, PHP, APACHE, & PHPMyAdmin, the install went well and all appears ok.

I used this site for guidance.

http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-mysql-phpmyadmin/

I then tried to reconnect to the PPTP running on the same unit.
Verifying username and password

I now get the error message
'Connecting to 192.168.10.18 using '
The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed. The VPN server might be unreachable. If this connection is attempting to use an L2TP/IPsec tunnel, the security parameters required for IPsec negotiation might not be configured properl'y

If I do a port scan of the Pi port 1723 does not appear to be open.

Could be the Mysql install has closed the PPTP port?

I have run

```
sudo netstat -alpn |grep :1723
```

and the output says

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2567/pptpd
```

Please can someone advise me of the best way to open the PPTP port?
Thanks